# Is this idea amenable to database storage? Is there an alternative?

Tags: database, nosql, rdbms

Imagine you have a very large set (say, 1 million+) set of "tasks", each requiring a small set of "resources" (maybe around 10 from a very large set, say 10,000+).

I'd like to perform a query that takes some sample set of "resources" (again, around 10), and would find all tasks which use these resources. Eventually, I'd like to perform more complex queries on the "tasks", such as:

- Which "tasks" require more "resources" than I have?
- How close is a given "task" to my "resource list"?

I think the problem is quite similar in some ways to a web search, where the "tasks" are web pages and the "resources" are the words on those pages. In the parallel problem, I want to perform queries such as "given these words, show me all the webpages that contain them each a specific number of times".

From what I can tell, this problem is *not* appropriate for regular databases (and even NoSQL databases!). The list of "resources" needs to be extensible, so it can't be a column in a traditional database. There will also be many of them, so it doesn't seem correct to make a database with 10,000 columns.

What I was imagining was trying to keep all of the data in memory, and just search it sequentially. But that's probably not very scalable and I'd lose all of the data if I lost power...

I'd love any guidance on how to solve problems like this!

Answer (score 1):

I would check out Neo4j (a graph database) and see if it fits your problem space.

http://www.neo4j.org/

Each task would be a node in the graph.

The nice thing about Neo4j is that it supports property graphs, which means each node can have key/value pairs. (http://www.neo4j.org/learn/graphdatabase). This means each node can have n number of resources associated with it.

There is no normalization here as you'd see with a regular relational database. Just key/value pairs with each node.

Gremlin is a DSL on top of Groovy that has a nice syntax for graph traversals and works with Neo4j. You can do your searching/queries/etc. with it.

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Gremlin-Query-Language

Comment: +1 Wow, interesting! I didn't even "graph databases" existed. It's great to learn new terms and ideas like this to examine if they're more appropriate for a problem. Thanks so much for your input!